# How to write a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a sp. My requirement is mentioned below:

**TableA:**

Id is Primary key.

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Col1   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Sample1 |
|  2 | Sample2 |
+----+---------+
```

**TableB:**

Id is Primary key.
Col1_Id is foreign key of TableA

```
+----+---------+-------+
| Id | Col1_Id | Col2  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | TestA |
|  2 |       1 | TestB |
|  3 |       2 | TestC |
+----+---------+-------+
```

**TableC:**

Id is Primary key.

```
+----+------------------------+
| Id |     QusetionText       |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | Sample Question One?   |
|  2 | Sample Question Two?   |
|  3 | Sample Euestion Three? |
+----+------------------------+
```

**My Output Should be;
TableD:**

Id is Primary key.
Col1_Id is foreign key of TableA
Col2_Id is foreign key of TableB

```
+----+------------+---------+---------+------------------------+
| Id | QuestionId | Col1_Id | Col2_Id |      QusetionText      |
+----+------------+---------+---------+------------------------+
|  1 | Q_2013     |       1 |       1 | Sample Question One?   |
|  2 | Q_2013     |       1 |       1 | Sample Question Two?   |
|  3 | Q_2013     |       1 |       1 | Sample Question Three? |
|  4 | Q_2013     |       1 |       2 | Sample Question One?   |
|  5 | Q_2013     |       1 |       2 | Sample Question Two?   |
|  6 | Q_2013     |       1 |       2 | Sample Question Three? |
|  7 | Q_2013     |       2 |       3 | Sample Question One?   |
|  8 | Q_2013     |       2 |       3 | Sample Question Two?   |
|  9 | Q_2013     |       2 |       3 | Sample Question Three? |
+----+------------+---------+---------+------------------------+
```

Please tell me how to write query to get TableD.

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Comment: Cant see any relation between tablec and other tables.

Comment: totally.Each record from TableA contains one or more records in TableB.I need to create a table(TableD) where records from TableC wil get inserted wrt to TableB records. Totally TableD contains 3x3 records (#TableB x #TableC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This Out,

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Prathiba
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
 CREATE PROCEDURE SampleProc 

 AS
 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
           SELECT dbo.TableA.Id, dbo.TableB.Col1_Id, dbo.TableC.Id AS Col2_Id, dbo.TableC.QuestionText
           FROM   dbo.TableA INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TableB ON dbo.TableA.Id = dbo.TableB.Col1_Id CROSS JOIN
                  dbo.TableC
 END
 GO
```

Please make sure that there is no relation with your **TableC** ie., why cross join is using.